# Run and stop timer using class field in TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript, class, setinterval, clearinterval

I would like to create the class containing a field with timer. The main problem is that
I can't set the timer default value undefined or null, because TypeScript doesn't allow this.
I need to create an empty timer and run or stop it with relevant class methods. Now this script doesn't even run necessary timer with entered interval when I call start method.

```
class Test {
  timer: NodeJS.Timer = setInterval(() => { console.log('1') }, 1000);

  start(interval: number) {
    this.timer = setInterval(() => console.log('Timer is working!'), interval);
  }

  stop() { clearInterval(this.timer); }
}

const test = new Test();

test.start(5000);

test.stop();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define the `timer` as `NodeJS.Timer | null` and init it with `null`. Check that the timer is initialized when calling `stop`, and also assign `null` to timer after clearing it:

```
class Test {
  timer: NodeJS.Timer | null = null;

  start(interval: number) {
    this.stop();
    this.timer = setInterval(() => console.log('Timer is working!'), interval);
  }

  stop() {
    if(this.timer) {
      clearInterval(this.timer);
      this.timer = null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I've edited my script, however the start method doen't work when I run it in shell with ts-node.

Comment: Just checked locally. It works fine with ts-node. Which version are you using?

Comment: [Ori Drori](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5157454/ori-drori) I think that my script doesn't work because of stop method calling at the end. It stops timer immediately and start method doesn't even start.

Comment: lol. I've entered it manually to ts-node, so it worked, and then stopped when I called stop.

Comment: I have the same behaviour with script execution. Now it's working the way I thought it would. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Btw, the improvement here is to call `stop` in `start` to not spawn hidden timers.

Comment: Why are hidden timers going to be spawn? When I call the stop method, it clears the created before timer. Are there any unobvious circumstances?

Comment: @alexmac is right. Calling start multiple times would create hidden timers, unless we stop the previous one, when we start a new one. See the updated `start` method.

Comment: Oh, I understand what you are talking about. This sounds reasonable and I had updated the start method earlier to prevent running multiple timers as you and @alexmac said. Thanks for your response.